# how to recover from deleting zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, root

So I was a bit aggressive in cleaning up my MacBook, and used my big brain to deleted `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. Now, of course, Terminal flips out.

I've successfully booted into single-user mode and mounted my disks.

I've unsuccessfully tried to `chsh` of what I thought would be my user(name):

```
# /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/chsh -s /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/bin/zsh aronhoyer
chsh: unknown user: aronhoyer
```

…curious. How about we try to just list out the users?

```
# dscl . list /Users | grep -v ^_
daemon
nobody
root
```

hmmm…

```
# dscl . list /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users | grep -v ^_
daemon
nobody
root
```

I have thus exhausted my knowledge of how to work the Terminal. So I turn to you, trusted community.

help pls

Comment: In single-user mode, `opendirectoryd` is not running, and it's what provides access to the normal user accounts.

Comment: aah that makes sense, @GordonDavisson! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out all I had to do was open up the terminal settings, and set a different path for the login shell

[image]

Comment: You should also run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` (note: no `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`, that just confuses things) now that you're back to normalish.

Comment: you better believe that was the first thing i did  think i'll have nightmares about this for a while